# How to skip image tag in html data in android?

Tags: android

My data in db is stored in html format along with image tags in it. So when I am getting the data from database I am removing the html tags and setting it to textview. My problem is even after removing the html tags, there is a small square box displaying in the emulator indicating that there is some image. How can I remove those square box in emulator which is an indication of image in that html data? Help me regarding this...

Thanks in advance

My Code:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString));
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could do a regex replace `<img.+?>` on `htmlString`.

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString.replaceAll("<img.+?>", "")));
```

*Untested*

Comment: I added the example (or the straight answer -- untested) on my answer above. Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

since images can look like:

```
<img ...></img>
```

and

```
<img... />
```

This solution will match both cases:

```
String htmlBody = htmlString.replaceAll("<img.+/(img)*>", "");
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlBody));
```

Answer (score 7):

None of the answers are able to remove all possible `img` tags.

The most appropriate answer would be

```
String htmlBody = htmlString.replaceAll("(<(/)img>)|(<img.+?>)", "");
```

It will remove  and  tags both. And not remove any content between two images.

Comment: If anyone is looking for a Kotlin answer, you have to use Regex object.
`string.replace(Regex("(<(/)img>)|(<img.+?>)"), "")`

Answer (score 0):

hi have a look on this example

```
     String temp="<img>helloo</img><b> this is test</b>";
     temp=   temp.replace("<img>", "");
     temp=   temp.replace("</img>", "");
             textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(temp));
```